# If-else statement working in one server but not working in another server

Tags: php, if-statement

I am having a weird problem. The given code is working fine in one server but when I am using it on another server it is not working. What may be problem?

```
$status=htmlentities($result->Status);

if ($status==0){

    $st="Letter not received by CRDS";
    $color=Red;
} elseif($status==1){
    $st="Letter received by CRDS";
    $color=Blue;
} elseif($status==2){
    $st="Letter Despatched";
    $color=Green;                                   
}
```

Comment: Are `Red`, `Blue` and `Green` defined constants? It's better to make a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can also check [the PHP error log](https://rollbar.com/guides/php/where-are-php-errors-logged/#).

Comment: Take a look at the manual [for `htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and see what it returns! It does not return a number

Comment: First thing to check would be that you are using the same version of PHP on both environments

Comment: PS: Whats an "If Loop" when its at home with its boots off

Comment: `if` is not a loop. Loops are things that execute code repeatedly, e.g. `for`, `while`, and `foreach` (the metaphor is that a loop goes around and around).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Red Blue green are used to define the css property.THis code is working fine in one machine ,when i am using it on other achine it doesnt work

Comment: But `$color=Blue;` for example is not valid PHP code unless you have defined `Blue` as something. That was the point of @KIKOSoftware comment

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for your feedback .It is solved  thnks

Comment: Debugging and checking the docs can be very helpful in figuring out these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as per the suggestion in the comments and I could solve it, but still, it is strange that it was working fine on another machine.

```
$status=htmlentities($result->Status);

if ($status==0){
    $st="Letter not received by CRDS";
    $color='Red';
} elseif($status==1){
    $st="Letter received by CRDS";
    $color='Blue';
} elseif($status==2){
    $st="Letter Despatched";
    $color='Green';                                   
}
```

Comment: Probably on the other machine you have error reporting turned off, always a dangerous thing to do when developing